# Fetch fields from two tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, one which stores the registered students, lets call it **students_register**.
The second table keeps examination details of the students, lets call it **exam_details**.
In the students_register table, i store:

```
student registration number    
first name    
last name    
email_address    
date_of_birth
```

and other details.

In the exam_details table, i store the registration number and the students marks in the different subjects.

Now, the challenge is that i want to query the **exam_details** table and display the data in a table but instead of displaying the students registration number, i want to associate the registration number in the exam_details table to that in the **students_register** table so that i can display the student's names instead of the registration number.

How can i go about this?

**1. students_register table**

```
id reg_number first_name  last_name  email_address      dob
1   P2894      John        Smith       john@example.com   12/05/1990
```

**2. exam-details table**

```
id reg_number english maths chemistry  biology physics
1  P2894       60%    80%    50%         72%     64%
```

How do i display this data in a table such that i have

```
first_name last_name  english  maths  chemistry  biology physics
 John       Smith      60%      80%    50%        72%    64%
```

Comment: It's called a "join".

Comment: what about mysql join tables -http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html - from your sample key would be reg_number like <<SELECT sr.first_name,  sr.last_name, ed.english,  ed.maths, ed.chemistry,  ed.biology, ed.physics 
from [exam-details] ed 
LEFT JOIN [students_register] sr ON sr.reg_number = ed.reg_number;>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT tb2.first_name, tb2.last_name, tb1.english, tb1.maths, tb1.chemistry, tb1.bilogy, tb1.physics
FROM exam_details AS tb1
INNER JOIN students_register AS tb2
ON tb1.reg_number = tb2.reg_number
```

Take a look at SQL Joins -> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 1):

With a simple JOIN query:

```
SELECT id, student_register.reg_number, first_name, 
       last_name, english, maths, chemistry, etc 
FROM student_register
JOIN exam-details ON student_register.reg_number = exam-details.reg_number
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `JOIN` here. I think this is the easiest way.

```
SELECT 
  sr.first_name, 
  sr.last_name, 
  ed.english, 
  ed.maths, 
  ed.chemistry, 
  ed.biology, 
  ed.physics 
FROM 
  students_register sr, 
  exam_details ed 
WHERE 
  sr.reg_number = ed.reg_numver
```

Comment: This is a join, too. Just another way of writing it. It will result in the same execution plan as a 'regular JOIN'.

Comment: Have actually learnt a new way of joining tables. Your answer works well, Thanks indeed.

Answer (score 1):

See for `JOIN`.

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, english, maths, chemistry, biology, physics FROM exam_details AS ex JOIN students_register st ON (ex.reg_number = st.reg_number)
```

Comment: This works well too. Thanks for the immediate answers. Am overwhelmed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM student-register INNER JOIN exam-details ON student-detail.reg_number=exam-details.reg_number
```

may be your query. Then you print out whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
select first_name, last_name, english, maths, chemistry, biology, physics
from students_register, exam_details
where students_register.reg_number=exam_details.reg_number
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to join these 2 tables

```
SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name, e.english, e.maths, e.chemistry; e.biology, e.physics FROM students_register s LEFT JOIN exam_details e USING (reg_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help u.

select students_register.first_name,students_register.last_name,exam-details.english, exam-details.maths, exam-details.chemistry,  exam-details.biology,  exam-details.physics from exam-details left join students_register on students_register.reg_number=exam-details.reg_number